# How can I trigger the width style of a class to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these 2 objects in my **HTML**:

```
//1st object
<span class="ui-slider-handle" tabindex="0" style="left: 15.3153%;"></span>

//2nd object
<div id="waveform">
  <wave style="display: block; position: relative; user-select: none; height: 50px; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;">
      <canvas></canvas>
      <wave style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; left: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 0px; display: block; box-sizing: border-box; border-right: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);"><canvas width="350" height="50" style="width: 350px;"></canvas></wave>
  </wave>
</div>
```

Is it possible using Javascript/jQuery connect the percentage of the "left" css attribute of the `ui-slider-handle` class to the width of the inner `wave` and triggering all the time the percentage (of the 1st object) change?

**My 1st try**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var playlist = [{
      title:"Hidden",
      artist:"Miaow",
      mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-02-Hidden.mp3",
      oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-02-Hidden.ogg",
      poster: "https://i.imgur.com/sCbrzQa.png"
    },{
      title:"Cro Magnon Man",
      artist:"The Stark Palace",
      mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3",
      oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.ogg",
      poster: "https://i.imgur.com/lXvsuBu.png"
    },{
      title:"Bubble",
      m4a: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a",
      oga: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg",
      poster: "https://i.imgur.com/klJKSVZ.jpg"
  }];
  
  var cssSelector = {
    jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer",
    cssSelectorAncestor: ".music-player"
  };
  
  var options = {
    swfPath: "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jplayer/2.6.4/jquery.jplayer/Jplayer.swf",
    supplied: "ogv, m4v, oga, mp3",
    volumechange: function(event) {
      $( ".volume-level" ).slider("value", event.jPlayer.options.volume);
    },
    timeupdate: function(event) {
      $( ".progress" ).slider("value", event.jPlayer.status.currentPercentAbsolute);
    }
  };
  
  var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, playlist, options);
  var PlayerData = $(cssSelector.jPlayer).data("jPlayer");
  
  
  // Create the volume slider control
  $( ".volume-level" ).slider({
     animate: "fast",
  max: 1,
  range: "min",
  step: 0.01,
  value : $.jPlayer.prototype.options.volume,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
   $(cssSelector.jPlayer).jPlayer("option", "muted", false);
   $(cssSelector.jPlayer).jPlayer("option", "volume", ui.value);
  }
  });
  
  // Create the progress slider control
  $( ".progress" ).slider({
  animate: "fast",
  max: 100,
  range: "min",
  step: 0.1,
  value : 0,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
   var sp = PlayerData.status.seekPercent;
   if(sp > 0) {
    // Move the play-head to the value and factor in the seek percent.
    $(cssSelector.jPlayer).jPlayer("playHead", ui.value * (100 / sp));
   } else {
    // Create a timeout to reset this slider to zero.
    setTimeout(function() {
      $( ".progress" ).slider("value", 0);
    }, 0);
   }
  }
 });

  $( ".ui-slider-range" ).slider({
    change: function( event, ui ) {
      $('wave').css('width', ui.value)
    }
  });  

  
});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.music-player {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 370px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #222;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}
.music-player img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
          filter: blur(2px);
}
.music-player .info {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #222;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.music-player .info .jp-playlist li {
  display: none;
}
.music-player .info .jp-playlist li a {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.4);
}
.music-player .info .jp-playlist li a span {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.music-player .info .jp-playlist li.jp-playlist-current {
  display: block;
}
.music-player .info .jp-playlist li .jp-free-media, .music-player .info .jp-playlist li .jp-playlist-item-remove {
  display: none;
}
.music-player .info .left, .music-player .info .right {
  width: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
}
.music-player .info .right {
  left: auto;
  right: 30px;
}
.music-player .info [class^="icon-"] {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.music-player .info .center {
  padding: 20px 0 0;
}
.music-player .progress, .music-player .volume-level {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
.music-player .progress .ui-slider-range, .music-player .volume-level .ui-slider-range {
  display: block;
  background: #ed553b;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.music-player .progress .ui-slider-handle, .music-player .volume-level .ui-slider-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 22px;
  background: url("//i.imgur.com/tsqwz1N.png") no-repeat center;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 -3px;
  cursor: move;
}
.music-player .controls {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 190px;
  background: #982e4b;
  background: rgba(152, 46, 75, 0.6);
}
.music-player .controls .current {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #fff;
  color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.4);
  padding: 15px 0 20px;
}
.music-player .controls .play-controls a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 30px;
}
.music-player .controls .volume-level {
  position: relative;
  bottom: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  background: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.3);
}
.music-player .controls .volume-level .ui-slider-range {
  height: 2px;
}
.music-player .controls .volume-level .ui-slider-handle {
  top: -8px;
  margin-left: -9px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/106/106874.svg");
}
.music-player .controls .volume-level .icon-volume-up, .music-player .controls .volume-level .icon-volume-down {
  position: absolute;
  right: -34px;
  top: -8px;
  width: 22px;
}
.music-player .controls .volume-level .icon-volume-down {
  right: auto;
  left: -27px;
}

[class^="icon-"] {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background: url("//i.imgur.com/E09T8tf.png") no-repeat center;
  display: block;
}

.icon-shuffle {
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148739.svg");
}
.icon-heart {
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/126/126499.svg");
}
.icon-repeat {
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/137/137485.svg");
}
.icon-share {
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/189/189676.svg");
}
.icon-previous {
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/137/137518.svg");
}
.icon-play {
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148744.svg");
}
.icon-pause {
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/189/189639.svg");
}
.icon-next {
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/137/137517.svg");
}
.icon-volume-up {
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149139.svg");
}
.icon-volume-down {
  background-image: url("http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/109/109699.svg");
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jplayer/2.6.4/jquery.jplayer/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jplayer/2.6.4/add-on/jplayer.playlist.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.0.52/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="music-player">
  <div style="background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/welcome-summer-badge-on-blurry-background_23-2147511412.jpg);" class="album"></div>

  <div class="info">
    
    <div class="left">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-shuffle"></a>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-heart"></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="center">
      <div class="jp-playlist">
        <ul>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="right">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-repeat"></a>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-share"></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="progress"></div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="demo">
  <div id="waveform">
  </div>

  <script>
    var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
    var linGrad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 64, 0, 200);
    linGrad.addColorStop(0.5, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.000)');
    linGrad.addColorStop(0.5, 'rgba(183, 183, 183, 1.000)');

    var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
      container: '#waveform',
      waveColor: linGrad,
      progressColor: 'hsla(200, 100%, 30%, 0.5)',
      cursorColor: '#fff',
      normalize: true,
      backend: 'MediaElement',
      height:50,
      barWidth: 3
    });
//Set peaks
wavesurfer.backend.peaks = [0.0218, 0.0183, 0.0165, 0.0198, 0.2137, 0.2888, 0.2313, 0.15, 0.2542, 0.2538, 0.2358, 0.1195, 0.1591, 0.2599, 0.2742, 0.1447, 0.2328, 0.1878, 0.1988, 0.1645, 0.1218, 0.2005, 0.2828, 0.2051, 0.1664, 0.1181, 0.1621, 0.2966, 0.189, 0.246, 0.2445, 0.1621, 0.1618, 0.189, 0.2354, 0.1561, 0.1638, 0.2799, 0.0923, 0.1659, 0.1675, 0.1268, 0.0984, 0.0997, 0.1248, 0.1495, 0.1431, 0.1236, 0.1755, 0.1183, 0.1349, 0.1018, 0.1109, 0.1833, 0.1813, 0.1422, 0.0961, 0.1191, 0.0791, 0.0631, 0.0315, 0.0157, 0.0166, 0.0108];

//Draw peaks
wavesurfer.drawBuffer();
  </script>
  
  </div>    
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="current jp-current-time">00:00</div>
    <div class="play-controls">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-previous jp-previous" title="previous"></a>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-play jp-play" title="play"></a>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-pause jp-pause" title="pause"></a>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-next jp-next" title="next"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="volume-level">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-volume-up" title="max volume"></a>
      <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-volume-down" title="mute"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="jquery_jplayer" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
  
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

The code above creates 2 different slider selector, also the slider affect the width of the wave object. Instead of I need something like this:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "triggering all the time the percentage (of the 1st object) change" ? What did you try so far?

Comment: so in this case `<wave style="width: 15.3153%" ...`

Comment: much better to update the question with clarification. Currently the question is not clear enough.

Comment: @SimonLeCat So you want to update the CSS of "ui-slider-handle" using jQuery (all the time/constantly?)

Comment: @DerGoliHerr I want to update the width of the inner `wave` with the same percentage value of the `ui-slider-handle`

Comment: @Dekel first I tried getting the width of the 1st object like `$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ui-slider-range").css('width');
});` but I saw that it fires only the first time and not on change value

Comment: @SimonLeCat In that case, you should use a specific event to trigger the update process, first getting the percentage value of `ui-slider-handle` and then applying it to the inner `wave` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you're using the [UI Slider](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/) from jQuery. Once you initialise it, you can use the `change` event as follows:

```
$( ".ui-slider-handle" ).slider({
  change: function( event, ui ) {
    $('wave').first().next().css('width', ui.value)
  }
});
```

Edit: I just realised you wanted the second wave so I added `.next()`

Comment: It is not the **value**  attribute he wants to register, but **style**. Or does one respond to another?

Comment: If you read the docs, value represents the current value of the slider. In OP's situation, width represents the latter

Comment: I tried but it's not working as expected, could you please check my example? It takes the 1st wave I think

Comment: You can always remove .first() and it will apply the condition in every `wave` element

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [MutationObserver()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). It allows you to register any change in `element`'s attribute and act on it.

Be sure to **check browser support**, as it is very likely that it does not include what you actually need.